# Spark: Cannot run program "jupyter"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, hadoop-yarn

When I submit a python file to yarn, I meet this error:

```
ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jupyter": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jupyter": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:637)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

I submit by :

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--executor-memory 8g \
--driver-memory 10g \
--num-executors 100 \
--executor-cores 10 \
test.py
```

I try to set `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` in `~/.bashrc`, but meet another error: `/opt/bin/python: No such file or directory`.

But I'm sure I the file `/opt/bin/python` exists.

The `.bashrc` files is as follows:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<


# Auto deploy profile
source /etc/profile
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
@
"~/.bashrc" 76L, 2780C
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export SPARK_HOME=/home//spark2
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin

# hadoop
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar
# JAVA
#export CLASSPATH=$(JARS=("$LIB"/*.jar); IFS=:; echo "${JARS[*]}")
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar

# Jupyter notebook for pyspark
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I can run my code on local spark successfully.

Any solution for it?

Comment: please share the code that you have written, along with the contents of your `bashrc` file

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem. Following solution solve my issue

```
update ~/.bashrc as below

PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```